# Dynamodb query with GSI and filter expression on non partition key and sort key columns in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I have a GSI on my table and am using that GSI for querying results. Am using a filter expression as well

```
const active_cases = await storesMonthlyAudit();
console.info("actives cases : ", active_cases)

async function storesMonthlyAudit() {
    const params = {
        TableName: "jms-case-management-dev",
        IndexName: "entity-sKey-index",
        ProjectionExpression: "storeId,caseId",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#entity = :entity",
        FilterExpression: "#status = :status",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#entity": "entity",
            "#status": "status",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":entity": "Case",
            ":status": "Active"
        }
    };
    const cases = await Query(params);
    return cases
}
```

Response :

```
actives cases :  {
  Items: [],
  Count: 0,
  ScannedCount: 8012,
  LastEvaluatedKey: { entity: 'Case', sKey: 'C#10134066', pKey: 'ST#1013' }
}
```

But when I tried the same thing from AWS console, I get the correct result of 2 records with status = "Active"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB will only access 1MB of data for each query request. This data access is counted before any filters or projection expressions. It appears you have more than 1 MB of data stored under your specified partition key. You need to make multiple requests to access all of the data.

The console used the `LastEvaluatedKey` from the response to make additional queries. You can see it consumed 559 RCUs when running your query, which means it made 5 requests in total for you to find these two values.

You likewise need to make multiple queries. You do this by setting the `ExclusiveStartKey` on subsequent requests, setting this value as the `LastEvaluatedKey` from the previous request. When `LastEvaluatedKey` is not returned from a request, you know that you have searched through all items that match your query.

Answer (score 0):

I read about LastEvaluatedKey and ExclusiveStartKey and wrote a small function

```
async function dbRead(params) {
  let result = await db.query(params).promise();
  let data = result.Items;
  if (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
    data = data.concat(await dbRead(params));
  }
  return data;
}
```